# After success validation also getting error message but its processing in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Dynamic Action ->When:click button->If:True->submit page.here i am doing a validation with a sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM TAB_MASTER
WHERE REQUEST_ID=:P4_SELECTED_REQ_ID AND (upper(USER_NAME)=upper(:APP_USER) OR 
EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM USER_ACCOUNT WHERE USER_ROLE='ADMIN' AND upper(USER_NAME)=upper(:APP_USER)));
```

means request can be confirmed by same user or another user with ADMIN role.if the above query will return 1 row only should process otherwise error message (no process).If there is no record(another user and no admin role) its working fine.but when it return 1 record(another user and admin role) its processing but error message is getting pop up what used for FALSE condition.

Also tried to set value to the output sql query to a hidden field then used validation as plsql/expression :HIDDEN_FIELD=1,but no luck.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking, sorry. Have you implemented the validation in the On Submit processing part of the page? What type of validation have you used (e.g. "Rows Returned")?

Comment: yes i used Row Returned.If there is no row return by the sql query its working (getting error message).If row return also i am getting same user define error message..but record is processing.

Comment: If a validation fails it shouldn't run any processes. There's something missing in your explanation - perhaps some screenshots of the validation and process attributes might help.